# Optimisation advices and AJAX loading on wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm currently finishing my portfolio that I've made using wordpress 3.8 and customizing the team's template (TwentyFourteen), since it's my first time trying to do something cool with wordpress.
Go there in order to have a look : http://micheldidier.com

This last part is about optimisation. I've already argued a bit with my host because of a long wait time befor first byte reception. It was their bad and it changed a bit after they add a few other server. I've used W3 Total Cache to speed up a bit, and setup Cloud Flare. Don't really know if it's a good practice or not...

The problem is that I've made an AJAX navigation. And I don't know if I did it the good way... why ?
Maybe the following numbers we'll change for you, but :

-When I'm loading the website for the first time, after I cleaned the cache, it's taking around 4 seconds to load.
-When I'm clicking on a project link/and or another page, it's loading using ajax, but taking a lot more time...

Why is this taking so much time ? What should I do in order to change that? Using AJAX is supposed to load smoothly content, their is nothing good to use AJAX if it's taking much more time...

Here is my js code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(window).hashchange( function(){

        //finding the link
        var arg = window.location.hash.substring(3);
        var link = 'http://micheldidier.com/'+arg; //replacing root URI !!

        //requete ajax
        $.ajax({  
            url:link,
            processData:true, //Object result
            dataType:'html', //type html
            async: true, 
            complete: function(xhr, text) {},
            cache: true,
            error: function(xhr, text, e) {},
            global: true,
            headers: {},
            statusCode: {},
            success:function(data){
                // callback
                data = innerShiv(data,false);
                var thecontent = $(data).find("#content-article");
                var title = $(data).filter('title').text();
                document.title = title;
                $('#content-home').slideToggle('slow',function(){
                    $(this).html(thecontent).slideToggle('slow', function(){
                        $.scrollTo('#content-article', 600);
                        return false;
                        });
                });
            }
         });
    });

    //hash onload
    if(window.location.hash.substring(3)!=''){
        $(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );
    }
```

the question I'm asking is that if the problem is still because of my host. because of my jQ ? or because of PHP ?

Here is my homepage PHP code :

```
get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">
<div id="top-sidebar" class="top-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-4' ); ?>
</div><!-- #top-sidebar -->
<div id="content-home"></div>
<?php
    if ( is_front_page() && twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() ) {
        // Include the featured content template.
        get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
    }
?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                     * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                     * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content-home', get_post_format() );

                endwhile;
                // Previous/next post navigation.
                twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

            else :
                // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

            endif;


        ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- #main-content -->
<?php get_footer();
```

And here is my single page PHP code :

```
    if ($_GET["ajax"]==true) get_template_part('header-ajax');
else get_header(); ?>


    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content-article" class="site-content" role="main">
            <?php
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                     * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                     * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                    // Previous/next post navigation.
                    twentyfourteen_post_nav();

                endwhile;
            ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar( 'content' );
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

I think that's all, if you need anything else, feel free to ask ! if you got any other advices of "best practice" feel free to let me know !

Thanks for your time !!

Comment: Remember, that requesting a page with ajax will request the page in the same way that requesting the page normally will, with the exception that scripts/stylesheets/images won't begin to load until you add them to your page. If the request normally takes 4 seconds to be retrieved before the assets begin to load, it will still take 4 seconds.

Comment: if your drawing a ton of content after the ajax request using the .html() method, it could just be the browser taking a while to render it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what all is available with wordpress, but you can reduce the size of your request by detecting (possibly within the template?) whether or not the request is an ajax request or a normal request, then if it's an ajax request, only return the content required by the ajax request rather than everything.

Comment: So, in my "single page" PHP, I should, for exemple, only put this content, since all the rest is useless, everything is loaded with AJAX everywhere on the website :

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content-article" class="site-content" role="main">
            <?php
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

                    // Previous/next post navigation.
                    twentyfourteen_post_nav();

                endwhile;
            ?>